$P=S^{-1}$ and $Q = S[1:k, 1:k]^{-1}$. Can we write $Q$ in terms of $P$?
Let $S$ be an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix. For $k < n$, define
$$P= S^{-1}\quad\text{and}\quad Q=S[1\text{:}k,1\text{:}k]^{-1}$$
where $S[1\text{:}k,1\text{:}k]$ is the principal leading sub matrix of $S$ of size $k\times k$. We have access to the matrix $P$, but not $Q$ or $S$.
Question: Can we write the $(ij)^{th}$ element of $Q$ as a function of the entries of $P$ (in an efficient way)?
Of course this can theoretically be done, since we can get to $Q$ by inverting, throwing away information, and inverting again. I'm wondering if there's some nice formula or some nice way to do this efficiently (say $\mathcal O(n)$).

Efficiency aside, you may simply make use of Schur complement.
Let $P=\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}$, where $A$ is $k\times k$. Then $S=P^{-1}=\pmatrix{(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}$. Therefore $S[1:k,1:k]^{-1}=A-BD^{-1}C$.

+1, a helpful observation. Although thisis more efficient than the naive approach, but I don't think it solves my issue. For context, I need to find just three elements $Q_{k1}$, $Q_{00}$ and $Q_{kk}$, but I have to do this for every single $k$.
